# How to pass hardcoded List<Object> from View to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, model

How would one go about to pass a hardcoded List of Cards (a deck) from View to Controller. I've tried several different things to pass it, but with various results. My index is a screen with 52 cards where you can draw the top card, and I want to be able to shuffle them, and even add a new deck to the current deck, and update the hardcoded list.

This is some of the relevant code. Any suggestions?

EDIT: The formpost method is where I am not sure about. I could probably add just a new List of Cards in the Action, but then the issue will arise again when I try to add a new deck to the current deck.

```
public class Card
{

    public Suit Suit { get; set; }
    public Cardnumber Cardnumber { get; set; }

    public Card(Cardnumber c, Suit s)
    {
        this.Cardnumber = c;
        this.Suit = s;

    }

}
```

**DeckOfCardsViewModel.cs**

```
public class DeckOfCardsViewModel 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Card> Cards { get; set; }

}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (deck.Count < 1)
        {
            deck = new Deck().NewDeck();
            deckViewModel = new DeckOfCardsViewModel();
            deckViewModel.ID = 1;
            deckViewModel.Cards = deck;
            return View(deckViewModel);
        }

        else return View();

    }

    public ActionResult ShuffleDeck(DeckOfCardsViewModel shuffledDeck)
    {
        shuffledDeck.Cards = shuffledDeck.Cards.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
        deckViewModel = shuffledDeck;

        return View("Index",shuffledDeck);
    }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model DeckOfCards.Models.DeckOfCardsViewModel



  @using (Html.BeginForm("ShuffleDeck", "Home", ****FormMethod.Post?***))
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Cards);
    @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.ID);

    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="TEST" type="submit" value="Submit">Shuffle</button>
  }
```

Comment: http://www.altafkhatri.com/Technical/How-to-get-Ilist-value-from-ASP-net-mvc-postback/Bind-list-to-ASP-NET-MVC-object/Postback-object-list-binding i think this will help you